# SpringBoot Actuator logfile endpoint returns 404

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-404, spring-boot-actuator, logfile

Calling GET /actuator/logfile returns 404 error.

How can i get log via actuator/logfile?

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:8001/actuator/logfile -i
HTTP/1.1 404 
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 08:43:44 GMT
```

I have the configuration below.

I launched the application with 'local' profile.

I have log file in log folder( ex. api_log.2020-09-22-0.log ).

application.yml

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"

  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

logging:
  file:
    path: log
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="log/console.xml"/>
    <include resource="log/file.xml"/>
    <root level="info">
        <springProfile name="dev">
            <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
        </springProfile>
        <springProfile name="local">
            <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
        </springProfile>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

log/file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/api_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
</appender>
```

/actuator/logfile endpoint enables.

```
curl -XGET localhost:8001/actuator           
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator",
            "templated": false
        },
        "beans": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/beans",
            "templated": false
        },
        "caches": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/caches",
            "templated": false
        },
        "caches-cache": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/caches/{cache}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "health-path": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/health/{*path}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/health",
            "templated": false
        },
        "info": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/info",
            "templated": false
        },
        "conditions": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/conditions",
            "templated": false
        },
        "configprops": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/configprops",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env-toMatch": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/env/{toMatch}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "env": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/env",
            "templated": false
        },
        "logfile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/logfile",
            "templated": false
        },
        "loggers-name": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/loggers/{name}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "loggers": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/loggers",
            "templated": false
        },
        "heapdump": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/heapdump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "threaddump": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/threaddump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/metrics",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics-requiredMetricName": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "scheduledtasks": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/scheduledtasks",
            "templated": false
        },
        "mappings": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8001/actuator/mappings",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `application.yml`

```yaml
logging:
  file:
    path: log
```

to

```yaml
logging:
  path: log
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , replacing log4j.xml to logback.xml solved the issue

logback.xml

```
<property name="LOGS" value="/var/log/qhmhris/"/>

<appender name="Console"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/mockclientdirectory.log</file>
    <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/MHR-Batch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- note that maxFileSize must not greater than  totalSizeCap -->
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <!-- Keep no more than 4 months data. -->
        <maxHistory>120</maxHistory>
        <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 1GB, it will delete old archived file -->
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</root>

<!-- LOG "au.gov.qld.health.sit.mhr.batch*" at TRACE level -->
<logger name="au.gov.qld.health.sit.mhr.batch" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</logger>
```